# git credential-manager still prompts for password every time

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

We're using git-credential-manager and connecting via SSH to a remote git repository which we host.

But every time we push/pull it still prompts for a password. Any suggestions on how to configure this correctly? Please comment if you need more information.

Global config

```
[credential]
    helper = 
    helper = git-credential-manager
```

Repository config

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://username@remoteip:/path/to/repository.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote origin URL is an SSH one.

That means the git credential helper is *not* involved. At all.

What Git would ask through SSH is the passphrase of the private key or, if you do not have a registered public key in `~remoteip:/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys`, the actual password for the remote user '`username`'.

The [`ssh-agent`](https://smallstep.com/blog/ssh-agent-explained/) can help cache the passphrase.
But make sure your public key is registered on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75460209/4166932) for pointing me in the right direction.

As he says, if using SSH, the credential manager is not used at all.

On the client run the following

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Browse to the folder where you created the key and run

```
ssh-add your_key_file_name
```

You may need to first run

```
start ssh-agent
```

to get the [service running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement).

This creates two files in the folder you specify. Copy the contents (the public key) from the .pub file.

On the remote, paste the public key into the /home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys file. Create the file if it doesn't exist.

This then worked for me when pushing and pulling from command line.

Comment: Good feedback, well done. At the same time, you can test an HTTPS access using an HTTP URL for your remote repository. *Then* your credential helper would be useful. However, for an on-premise server, sometimes only SSH is setup to listen to remote queries.